# Angular Material Tree View Without Icons

Tags: angular, angular-material, treeview, angular7

All of the examples I have found online for the Angular Material Tree Views use an icon to expand or retract the child nodes. Can anyone give any examples of how to use the Material Tree View which expands or retracts by clicking on the parent text?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Any code to show ?

Comment: I have used the examples from [https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview]. The example they have showing code is [https://stackblitz.com/angular/vnpmjrvjaky?file=app%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.ts]. It just uses icons as buttons instead of having the parent text as the button.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this was a silly question. Found out that the answer was as simple as placing the {{node.name}} in between the button tags and deleting the icon tags. While using the examples from material.angular's website.